# Android: can't change textView height value to bigger one on runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, height, textview, android-textattributes

I have a Fragment which layout contains a TextView in a LinearLayout. I want on Runtime to change dynamically the height of the textView, and i get successfully to change it to a lower value than the originally, it seems to work. But when I put an upper value, the textView only adjust its height at most to parent height. (i've checked parent height and its value is always 592)

fragment_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/af_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/tv_size" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

FrgmentClass.java

```
TextView mTv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mTextView);

int newHeight = value;

mTv.setHeight(value);
```

If value is a low value like 200 it works, but for a bigger value like 1000 it doesn't, textview only resizes to parent height at most.

I've tried this too but not results with any value, although lower or upper than original value.

```
mTv.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED,MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

// New measure values
int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(1200, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

mTv.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
```

i've tried using invalidate(), requestLayout() and refreshDrawableState() but the problem presists.

**EDIT 1**

I've setting up textView height value static in xml file, longer than his parent and it works (although i would like to set it up dynamically)

```
android:layout_height="1000dp"
```

So textView looks like this the layout:

fragment_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/af_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1000dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/tv_size" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

But now on runtime i set up scrolling method to textview and it does nothing, and not scrolling:

FrgmentClass.java

```
TextView mTv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mTextView);

mTv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Why it not scrolls?

Comment: it will make the textView as big as his parent allow it. Eventually you can make the textView scrollable

Comment: Trying to apply your answer but a new problem. I've edited the question! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the linearLayout in scrollview like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/af_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/tv_size" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks! it works, but only if i put static value in height attribute in the xml file!

Answer (score 0):

Just set the

```
android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

properties of your TextView in your layout's xml file.

And then use:

```
textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

in your code.